# R markdown source R code doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

This seems simple but I can't get my head around why it isn't working...
I have a Rmarkdown file(test.Rmd) in which I'm sourcing an R file(test1.R), the code in sourced R file doesn't seem to access the objects in Rmarkdown file - why?

content of test.Rmd :

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---
```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis',message=FALSE}
library(data.table)
x<-data.table(a=1,b=2)
source("test1.R")
{knitr::kable(x1)}
```
````

Content of test.R

```
x1<-x
```

The error while running the document is :

```
Error : Object 'x' not found
```

Why doesn't sourced commands couldn't access the objects in the calling scope?

Comment: It seems related to shiny. When I try with a regular Rmarkdown document (remove `runtime: shiny`), it works fine.

Comment: When you use `shiny` the environment that the program is run in and the environment that the source file is loaded into are not the same so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need

```
source("test1.R",local=TRUE)
```